# How setup macports package bash to be used from terminal.app

Tags: terminal, bash, macports

I've made a bit of confusion trying to make terminal.app use /opt/local/bin/bash installed from macports as shell.
I've used:

```
chsh -s "/opt/local/bin/bash --rcfile ~/.profile -v"
```

trying also with -l option but still do not reads ~/.profile.
I've set also

```
/opt/local/bin/bash --rcfile ~/.profile -v -l
```

in terminal.app preferences.
Any suggestion to correctly set up terminal.app to use /opt/local/bin/bash and to load ~/.profile?
Thanks

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/453236/how-to-set-my-default-shell-on-mac

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From `man chsh`

```
The shell field is the command interpreter the user prefers.  If the shell field
is empty, the Bourne shell, /bin/sh, is assumed.  When altering a login shell, and
not the super-user, the user may not change from a non-standard shell or to a
non-standard shell.  Non-standard is defined as a shell not found in /etc/shells.
```

So to change your shell to `/opt/local/bin/bash` run

```
grep -q '^/opt/local/bin/bash' /etc/shells || sudo sh -c 'echo /opt/local/bin/bash >> /etc/shells'
chsh -s /opt/local/bin/bash
```

If you use bash as your login shell (which is what chsh and the default for Terminal.app do) then if you don't have ~/.bash_profile then bash will automatically read ~/.profile (but as you are using bash you should be using ~/.bash_profile)

Terminal.app by default runs login which runs the shell set by chsh and that should be loading macports bash and then ~/.profile

Comment: I've added some details from the man page.

Comment: Hi, thanks for answer very usefull. So option for custom shell in terminal.app preferences is for emergency purpose? I had also forgotten priority between .bash_profile and .profile

Comment: Everything works well just seems the options aren't read: just a -v for debug purpose ...

Comment: @AlexanderBeerhoff sorry I don't understand your comments

Comment: @mmmmmm sorry, I mean that I don't get the output expected for -v option (that I get when I set custom login shell from terminal.app preferences): don't know if I missed some quotes or output isn't shown in terminal in this scenario

Comment: You need to explain the exact things you did and how they differ from my answer